# Intelligent IGBT Module for Motor drive

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, h-bridge, motor-controller, igbt

I am looking for IGBT module for motor drive..
Approx. 50A, 1200V rating.
7 Pack module, Including Inverter + Brake circuit + Built-in drivers

For this I have found a module and it's datasheet mention that its 'Intelligent Power Module' but there is no detail about it that how it is intelligent..

I mean does it possess any machine learning features in it or in what sense it is an intelligent power module compared to other non-intelligent ones.

If anyone has any know-how about this please share your thoughts.

I am not writing the name of the company because it will violate the forum rules.

Here is the link to datasheet: https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/7mbp50rj120-datasheet.pdf

IPM = Intelligent Power Module

Comment: Link to datasheet in the question,  please.

Comment: this is its link: (i am worried that my question does not get blocked due to this marketing info.) https://pdf.direnc.net/upload/7mbp50rj120-datasheet.pdf

Comment: Datasheet links are essential so your question won't get blocked. Add it into your question so that all the information is in one place.I can't find the word "intelligent" in that datasheet.

Comment: IPM means Intelligent Power Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intelligent Power Module simply refers to a more integrated solution when it comes to what is needed from a power core.

At the very least this includes the inverter switches and associated gatedrives in one package reducing overall BOM, area/volume

In one example on the market, this highly integrated power module also includes the 3phase current sensing and the driver signal and feedback all across a digital bus.

Comment: OK. this makes sense. So Intelligent has a new meaning here. more of a marketing term rather than academic meaning. Would you possibly tell which 'highly integrated power module' you pointed out in your answer?

Comment: Exactly. Refering to such items as an INTEGRATED power module would make more sense but some marketing guru at some point span INTELLIGENT when really they are not... I first used an IPM from Mitsubishi in 2001 and ran into no end of problems (in build desat was twitchy) there was no way to tweak it so it was a redesign to an econopak and discrete gatedrives

Comment: Can you comment on the price comparison between using an integrated power module vs discrete inverter design specially for 3-phase 5kW power level? Most probably an Integrated design would be expensive.. would that be 50% or more?